# Sencha Touch Panel setActiveItem not working

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I am building an app with Sencha touch. I have my viewport as a Carousel and inside that carousel there are 2 panels.

The second panel in that viewport is also a container for 2 nested panels.

```
App.views.Viewport = Ext.extend(Ext.Carousel, {
    fullscreen: true,
    indicator: false,
    layout: 'card',
    cardSwitchAnimation: 'slide',
    initComponent: function() {
        Ext.apply(App.views, {
            mainWindow: new App.views.MainWindow(),
            categories: new App.views.Categories()
        });
        Ext.apply(this, {
            items: [
                App.views.mainWindow,
                App.views.categories
            ]
        });

        App.views.Viewport.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});

App.views.Categories = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
    fullscreen: true,
    layout: 'card',
    cardSwitchAnimation: 'slide',
    initComponent: function() {
        Ext.apply(App.views, {
            categoriesList: new App.views.CategoriesList(),
            categoryDetail: new App.views.CategoryDetail()
        });
        Ext.apply(this, {
            items: [
                App.views.categoryDetail,
                App.views.categoriesList
            ]
        });
        App.views.Viewport.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

Here's the code for the categoriesList

```
Ext.regModel('Contact', {
    fields: ['firstName', 'lastName']
});

App.ListStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'Contact',
    sorters: 'firstName',
    getGroupString : function(record) {
        return record.get('firstName')[0];
    },
    data: [
        {firstName: 'Julio', lastName: 'Benesh'},
    ]
});

App.views.catsList = new Ext.List({
    store: App.ListStore,
    itemTpl: '<div class="contact"><div class="app_icon"><img src="images/angry-birds.png" width="50" height="50" /></div><div class="app_name"><strong>{firstName}</strong> {lastName}<br /><img src="images/rating-icon.gif" /></div></div>',
    onItemDisclosure: function(record, btn, index) {
        App.views.categories.setActiveItem(
                    App.views.categoryDetail, options.animation
                );
    }
});

App.views.CategoriesList = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {  
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [App.views.catsList],
    initComponent: function() {
        App.views.Categories.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

onItemDisclosure of the list elements is being triggered. however, the setActiveItem for the App.views.categories is not switching to categoryDetail. I've been struggling to get this working. Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in this line:

```
 App.views.categories.setActiveItem(
                App.views.categoryDetail, options.animation
            );
```

You see you have an `options` object that it's undefined. You should use this instead:

```
 App.views.categories.setActiveItem(
                    App.views.categoryDetail, {type:'slide', direction:'left'}
                );
```

Or other type of animation.

Do you get some error log? Maybe there are some other issues why it's not working.

**Update**

Add this

```
onItemDisclosure: function(record, btn, index) { 
console.log('onItemDis fired');
try{

  Ext.dispatch({ controller: App.controllers.AppsList, action: 'show', id: record.getId(), animation: { type:'slide', direction:'left' } }); 

}catch(e){
   console.log(e);
  }
}
```

Then in the controller :

```
App.controllers.MyController = new Ext.Controller({ show: function(options) { 
console.log('controller called');
try{
App.views.categories.setActiveItem( App.views.categoryDetail, options.animation );
}catch(e){console.log(e);} } });
```

then paste the console logs you get here.

Comment: Actually, this piece of code was in my controller, which is passed the object options. The problem is that i don't get no errors in my console whatsoever :S
'
App.controllers.MyController = new Ext.Controller({
    show: function(options) {
     App.views.categories.setActiveItem(
   App.views.categoryDetail, options.animation
        );
    }
});

Comment: How do you call it? What about that error log? It's really hard to guess like this...

Comment: on the catsList object i am handling the onItemDisclosure event:
onItemDisclosure: function(record, btn, index) {
     Ext.dispatch({
            controller: App.controllers.MyController,
            action: 'show',
            id: record.getId()
        });
    }

Comment: Well there you see, you are not passing any `animation` property. Try this  `onItemDisclosure: function(record, btn, index) { Ext.dispatch({ controller: App.controllers.MyController, action: 'show', id: record.getId(),animation:{type:'slide', direction:'left'} }); }`

Comment: Still no go, onces pressing the item the panel does nothing
onItemDisclosure: function(record, btn, index) {
     Ext.dispatch({
            controller: App.controllers.AppsList,
            action: 'show',
            id: record.getId(),
            animation: {
             type:'slide', 
             direction:'left'
      }
     });
    }

Comment: onItemDis fired
controller called
Nothing more or less

Comment: try changing this in `App.views.categories.setActiveItem( App.views.categoryDetail );` or `App.views.categories.setActiveItem( App.views.categoryDetail, {type:'slide',direction:'left'});` or `App.views.categories.setActiveItem( 0, options.animation );` or `App.views.categories.setActiveItem( 0);` . Also try issuing this in the console and see what happens.

Comment: All with the same effect. No exceptions in the console's log as well. I am wondering about why the original viewport works well while the inner categories panel doesn't :S